# styling display of border-bottom and hover for <a> inside <li>

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-lists

Here is my three view, I want the `border-bottom` not just for `<a>` text but for all border around the tree and same for `hover` `background-color`. here is html code for every `li`

**html**

```
<li ng-repeat="node in node.children" class="treebase"
        ng-include="'/_Core/DirectiveCore/Tree/NodeTemplate.html'" ng-show="node.isVisible">
        <a ng-click="c.nodeClicked($event , node)" class="treebase ">
            <span ng-class="node.currentCssClass" href="node.link"></span>
            {{node.text}}
        </a>
</li>
```

**css**

```
ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

ul li a.treebase:hover {
    text-decoration: none /*!important;*/ ;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    display: block;
}
```

**tree**

[image]

Comment: so what's the problem....

Comment: can you put this into a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

you can put the border on the li element instead if you want it to take full width since the li element is a block.

or you can simply change a to be displayed as block:

```
ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    display: block;
}
```

if a is displayed as block it will take full width inside li tag. as a result the border and background will take the width of li.